# Code formatting indents in HTML are appearing in the document

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML code that I copy and pasted from Anki (Flashcard creation program). The code works fine. (Background: the flashcard is a programming question)

```
<meta content="width=window-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

What does this code do?<div><div background-attachment:="" background-clip:="" background-image:="" background-origin:="" background-position:="" background-repeat:="" background-size:="" class="highlight" initial;="" initial;"=""><pre style="line-height: 25px;"><table class="highlighttable" style="font-family: Arial;"><tbody><tr><td><div 10px"="" class="linenodiv" padding-right:=""><pre style="line-height: 125%">1</pre></div></td><td class="code"><div class="highlight"><pre style="line-height: 125%">&lt;<span style="color: #008000; font-weight: bold">meta</span> <span style="color: #7D9029">http-equiv</span><span style="color: #666666">=</span><span style="color: #BA2121">"X-UA-Compatible"</span> <span style="color: #7D9029">content</span><span style="color: #666666">=</span><span style="color: #BA2121">"IE=edge"</span>&gt;</pre></div></td></tr></tbody></table></pre></div><div><center><br></center></div></div>
```

The code rendered on the browser:

[image: Correct formatting]

Obviously, this code is not readable in its current format. To fix this, I added the appropriate indentations.

```
<meta content="width=window-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

What does this code do?
<div>
  <div background-attachment:="" background-clip:="" background-image:="" background-origin:="" background-position:="" background-repeat:="" background-size:="" class="highlight" initial;="" initial;"="">
    <pre style="line-height: 25px;">
      <table class="highlighttable" style="font-family: Arial;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div 10px"="" class="linenodiv" padding-right:="">
                <pre style="line-height: 125%">1</pre>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="code">
              <div class="highlight">
                <pre style="line-height: 125%">&lt;<span style="color: #008000; font-weight: bold">meta</span> <
                  span style="color: #7D9029">http-equiv</span>
                  <span style="color: #666666">=</span>
                  <span style="color: #BA2121">"X-UA-Compatible"</span>
                  <span style="color: #7D9029">content</span>
                  <span style="color: #666666">=</span>
                  <span style="color: #BA2121">"IE=edge"</span>&gt;
                </pre>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </pre>
  </div>
  <div>
    <center>
      <br>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

The strange part: the indents above are now appearing in the HTML document.

[image: Code with indentations]

This shouldn't be happening, correct? I thought newlines in the HTML are not visible to users?

Comment: Its exactly what should happen, as you are using the <pre> tag which is supposed to use your formating. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `whitespace` is `pre` (preserved by the browser). This is intended so that you can indent code. Usually, when you want to render code in HTML you take off the indentation:

```
            <td class="code">
              <div class="highlight">
                <pre style="line-height: 125%">&lt;<span style="color: #008000; font-weight: bold">meta</span>
<span style="color: #7D9029">http-equiv</span>
<span style="color: #666666">=</span>
<span style="color: #BA2121">"X-UA-Compatible"</span>
<span style="color: #7D9029">content</span>
<span style="color: #666666">=</span>
<span style="color: #BA2121">"IE=edge"</span>&gt;
                </pre>
              </div>
            </td>
```

Notice that you don't need to do it on the `<pre>` line itself (and that is why the meta part shows with your desired indentation).

If you are going to be using code snippets frequently, a library such as  **[Prismjs](https://prismjs.com/)** will make your life much easier and be worth the overhead (it's a very lightweight library in fact):

```
<pre><code class="language-html">(... html code ...)</code></pre>
```